# Argument 1 missing or nil when trying to teleport player

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to code a brick in roblox that teleports you to a certain spot, when I try to run it however it gives me the error "Argument 1 missing or nil". Anyone know how to fix it?

```
Part = script.Parent 
Player = game:GetService("Players")
Part.touched:connect(function(touched)
    local specific = touched.parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    local SpecificPlayer = Player:GetPlayerFromCharacter()
    if specific == true then
        SpecificPlayer.PrimaryPart.Cframe = CFrame.new(Vector3(-91, 0.5, -7))
    end
 end)
```

I tried to search other instances of this issue but I Couldn't find an exact answer

Comment: Locate the exact line which causes that. Are you sure Vector3 implements __call correctly? Might be `Vector3.new()` instead

Comment: it says line 5 is causing it, Vector3.new doesn't work sadly

Comment: Oh yea you forgot to pass something to `GetPlayerFromCharacter`, I assume `specific` is meant  to be passed

Comment: now it doesn't give me the error but the actual script itself doesn't work lmao

Comment: I mean you check if specific is true. And since a model is never true I'm not sure what you expect here to happen at all. I assume you would like to check `if SpecificPlayer then` or something